# Rails - How to have a form save the data from multiple inputs as a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I'm building a page that contains a html table, where the user can choose the name in the table header and the content in the table row.

The user will enter the information to a form, which will be parsed into a hash and saved into the DB.

Here is an example where `:key` will be a key of the hash (table header text) and `:value` will be a value in the hash (table column content).

```
  <%= form_for([@page]) do |f| %>
   <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

   <%= f.text_field :key1 %>    
   <%= f.text_field :value1 %>

   <%= f.text_field :key2 %>    
   <%= f.text_field :value2 %>

   <%= f.text_field :key3 %>    
   <%= f.text_field :value3 %>

   <%= f.text_field :key4 %>    
   <%= f.text_field :value4 %>

   <%= f.submit "Save"  %>

 <% end %>
```

I could make a new DB table with a `has_many` association to the `page` DB and have the info stored in that table. Then that data can be rebuilt into a hash when I need to render the view.

But if I could save the entire hash into a column in the `page` DB, then it would save me from having to rebuild the hash every time someone visits the page.

I'm struggling to come up with how to do this in `form_for`.

The first issue is that it requires `key` and `value` columns in the `page` table. A simple fix would be change all inputs into `<%= f.text_field :html_table %>` (for `html_table` column in the `page` table). But then it won't be able to distinguish between a key and a value in the hash. And I also don't have any way of telling it to put the info together into a hash that is then stored into the `page` table's `html_table` column.

Not sure if this is even a possible thing but it doesn't hurt to ask before I go ahead with building the `has_many` association table and setting it up that way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm rather confused about your question.

Can't you build a hash like this in your controller action?

```
html_table = {
    params[:key1] => params[:value1],
    params[:key2] => params[:value2],
    params[:key3] => params[:value3],
    params[:key4] => params[:value4]
}
```

Then save it to `@page.html_table` attribute.

EDIT:

In this case, the form is not about attirbutes of a particular object. So instead of using form_for ([Link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for)), you should be using form_tag ([Link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag)).

Example:

```
<%= form_tag "/pages_controller/build_html_table" do %>
  <%= text_field_tag "key1" %>
  <%= text_field_tag "value1" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Its possible but what would the form look like? `text_field :key1` without the `f.`?

Comment: @user3234020 yes, you should be using a different helper. Check the edit

Comment: Ok I'll give it a go tomorrow.